# Impossible to display static images saved on tomcat server in a jsp after trying all context docBase configurations

Tags: image, jsp, tomcat

Im unable to display an image uploaded by a user on my local server (D:\fichiers)in a JSP, 
using pure Jee (no spring), Tomcat 9, intelli-j idea.

I've tried everything i could find :

I tried to add :

```
<Context docBase="D:\fichiers" path="/images"/>
```

in context.xml in meta-inf, in server.xml in Tomcat installation conf folder, in server.xml in Tomcat/conf of the app, in catalina/localhost/root.xml, in catalina/localhost/context.xml.

But i still get an error 404, images not found.

Here is the server.xml file :

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">                
    <Context docBase="D:\\fichiers" path="/images"/>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
</Host>
```

and the jsp call :

```
<c:set var="chemin">/images/</c:set>
<c:forEach items="${spot.photos}" var="photo">
<a href="${chemin}${photo.nom}" data-lightbox="gallerySpot"><img src="${chemin}${photo.nom}"/></a>
</c:forEach>
```

The only time it worked is when i checked on tomcat configuration

> Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance

But i had to remove it, cause Catalina was starting springframework on its own, and nothing worked properly after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer, and though it's stupidly simple, i couldn't find a place where it was said.
In Tomcat configuration tab in Intelli-j :

Deployment Tab -> Add external Source -> Select the local Drive -> Put URL desired in Application Context, and that's it !